# IAR - Adding pre-build command to increase build number

Tags: python, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, iar

I need to increase the version number every time I compile the project

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the Embedded Workbench IDE. To set up pre- or post-build actions in the IDE, open your project and

1. Choose Project>Options to display the Options dialog box.
2. Select Build Actions in the Category list.

This will take you to the build action dialog, where you can specify command lines for your pre- and post-build action. For more information check the IDE guide supplied with your Embedded Workbench.